# How to update a tableview's data which in the uiview view

Tags: iphone, uiview, delegates, tableview

Right now, I have a SubscribeViewController which has 2 views that are UIView's subclass. In these 2 views, I have added a tableview for each. SubscribeViewController conforms to a delegate that when I have chosen a brand, I want these 2 views' tableview to update their data. But how to do that? The code like this:

```
SubscribeViewController.m

@interface SubscribeViewController () <BrandsViewDelegate>

#pragma mark - BrandsViewDelegate
- (void)didSelectBrand:(Brand *)abrand
{
    //right here. how to update these 2 views' tableview data?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your View's subclass use

`@property` and `synthesize` both tableview inside subclass. (To access it inside `SubscribeViewController`)

```
SubscribeViewController.m

@interface SubscribeViewController () <BrandsViewDelegate>

#pragma mark - BrandsViewDelegate
- (void)didSelectBrand:(Brand *)abrand
{
    View1 *view1Obj=[[View1 alloc]initWithFrame:_givesomeframe_];
    View2 *view2Obj=[[View1 alloc]initWithFrame:_givesomeframe_];

    [view1.tableView1 reloadData];
    [view2.tableView2 reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** Instead of using `UIView` and then adding `UITableView` on them; You can directly add 2 `UITableView`.

**To answer your question:** Use `reloadData` method of `UITableView` like following:

```
[self.view1.tableView1 reloadData];
[self.view2.tableView2 reloadData];
```

**OR** If you go with my suggestion then:

```
[self.tableView1 reloadData];
[self.tableView2 reloadData];
```